# Strange JavaScript syntax in NodeJS examples

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen some NodeJS code examples on a couple of tech-blog sites with strange syntax. Have I been living under a rock or is this just the Syntax Highlighter playing silly buggers?

Example:

```
module.exports = (app) ->
  app.get '/', (req, res) ->
    res.send('hello world')
```

I presume the fact that this is an Express app is academic. Be gentle with your answers...

Comment: This is the coffeescript syntax and not javascript syntax

Comment: haha happened to me too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s not JavaScript; that’s [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org)! You’re not missing anything… in every sense.

(CoffeeScript’s npm package lets you run CoffeeScript under Node using `coffee`.)

Comment: Is "... in every sense" meant to be a shot at CoffeeScript?  I personally don't think it's worth learning an entirely new syntax for some semantic sugar, but I can see why some people would.  (Especially if they come more from a Pythonic background than C++/Java)

Comment: @Retsam: Yes, it is :) Maybe that belongs in a blog post, though.

Comment: @minitech I see your point. Just visited the CS link and suffered a huge yawn. Never thought I'd say "never" to a technology but my god that looks pointless. This says it all really: `The golden rule of CoffeeScript is: "It's just JavaScript"`

Answer (score 0):

The example code you have posted is [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), a Ruby/Python-like language that compiles directly to JavaScript. Here is an equivalent in JavaScript:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('hello world');
    });
};
```

Comment: Yeah I could pretty much make out the JavaScript equivalent - it's freakishly similar and therefore seemingly pointless? I've heard it's popular though.

Comment: @shennan It does make your code look cleaner and neater for the most part (as you can shorten various parts), but I guess it's primarily a stylistic choice, as there are no *real* benefits.